# Django - large file upload - moving file from temp folder to final destination fails

Tags: django, linux, docker, apache, alpine-linux

Stumbled upon this error when upgrading Python, Django and Alpine to latest versions... and it's a weird one.
The error occurs when I upload a file that is larger than FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE (set to 5MB).

I have two development environments set up.

- One is local dev server (just normal py manage.py runserver),
- the other one is running under Docker(Windows) + Alpine linux + Apache2 + mod_wsgi which is also still a 'development' environment.

This error occurs only under Docker environment and only when file exceeds max memory size. Under all other circumstances the upload works - even when file exceeds memory limit on local dev server.

The error:

```
Saving new order file to: customer_name/_web_portal/PendingOrders/7935/zip_03.zip 

Internal Server Error: /b2b_api/orders/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/code/api/views.py", line 352, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 19, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "/code/api/views.py", line 375, in perform_create
    serializer.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 212, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/code/api/serializers.py", line 286, in create
    instance = super().create(validated_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/code/api/serializers.py", line 125, in create
    db_file.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 814, in save
    self.save_base(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 877, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1020, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1061, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1805, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1821, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1745, in as_sql
    value_rows = [
                 ^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1746, in <listcomp>
    [
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1747, in <listcomp>
    self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1695, in pre_save_val
    return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 317, in pre_save
    file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 93, in save
    self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/files/storage/base.py", line 38, in save
    name = self._save(name, content)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/files/storage/filesystem.py", line 130, in _save
    os.chmod(full_path, self.file_permissions_mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sftp/customer_name/_web_portal/PendingOrders/7935/zip_03.zip'
```

The wierd thing about this is, when I look in to the folder, **the file is there**. And the user that Apache is running under, can access it.

Tried checking what's going on with `inotifywait` and this is the output for upload directory:

```
Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while!
Watches established.
/sftp/customer_name/_web_portal/PendingOrders/ CREATE,ISDIR 7982
/sftp/customer_name_web_portal/PendingOrders/ OPEN,ISDIR 7982
/sftp/customer_name/_web_portal/PendingOrders/ ACCESS,ISDIR 7982
/sftp/customer_name/_web_portal/PendingOrders/ CLOSE_NOWRITE,CLOSE,ISDIR 7982
# --> between those two records the error is thrown
/sftp/customer_name/_web_portal/PendingOrders/7982/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE zip_02.zip
```

Also tried editing django files before the error (right before the `os.chmod`...) and printing if file exists and here is the output:

```
os.listdir(directory)=['zip_10MB.zip']
os.path.exists(full_path)=False
os.path.isfile(full_path)=False
repr(full_path)="'/sftp/customer_name/_web_portal/PendingOrders/8013/zip_10MB.zip'" repr(directory)="'/sftp/customer_name/_web_portal/PendingOrders/8013'"
```

Which is unreal to me, because listdir outputs that the folder has a file in it, but `os.path.exists` outputs False?!
I found out that `os.path.exists()` and `isfile` call `os.stat()` underneath to find the necessary info, ... So I've tried `os.stat(full_path)` and it fails with FileNotFoundError.

After the error is thrown, I logged in to Docker with the same user the Apache is running under and tried running `os.stat()` on said file path, and it returns OK (fileinfo).

I've also checked what operation is Django using when moving the file from temp directory to it's final destination - it's django/core/files/move.py file_move_safe function - and it's a plain `os.rename()`

Next thing I've tried is to put `time.sleep()` before the actual error and `cd`-ing in upload directory and doing an `ls` command with each user and here is the output:
root user:

```
total 10432
drwxrwx---    1 web_port web_port       512 Aug 17 09:48 .
drwxrwx---    1 web_port web_port       512 Aug 17 09:48 ..
-rw-------    1 web_port web_port  10679630 Aug 17 09:48 zip_10MB.zip
```

web_portal ( apache / application ) user:

```
ls: ./zip_10MB.zip: No such file or directory
total 0
drwxrwx---    1 web_port web_port       512 Aug 17 09:48 .
drwxrwx---    1 web_port web_port       512 Aug 17 09:48 ..
```

Ps: I'm using `python:3.11-alpine` Docker image (Docker Desktop), with `Django==4.2.4` and `djangorestframework==3.14.0`.

Update:
Tried to place my Docker image / container on Linux OS - and the file upload works without an issue. So I'm guessing something is wrong with Docker for Windows, or how "bind" mount is handeled on Windows. Maybe?

Update #2:
Got an idea if maybe the file is being locked by Windows Defender or something.. idk I'm running out of ideas. So I've disabled Windows Defender, added exception on folder, .. the error remains. Next I've tried to enable Windows audit logging on folder but I have no idea on how to make sense from output of security log.

Has anyone any idea what the problem could be or what can I try next to further limit the cause of this problem?

Comment: For clarity, can you provide absolute path that you checked for with `ls` with root user and web_portal user? Since python script cannot find the file, I think the upgrade on windows might have somehow messed up with user access config.

Comment: Absolute? You mean full path? If not, absolute from what reference point?

I've checked it from inside the Docker container and the "ls" was executed from /sftp/customer_name/_web_portal/PendingOrders/8013 folder. The 8013 is just the current order id. On host system that path is C:/dev/web_portal/sftp/customer_name/_web_portal/PendingOrders/8013

Comment: ...It's the same path for both users

Comment: In that case, try giving `web_port` group read and write permission to the zip file and run `ls` as web_portal user again.

Comment: This is probably set by Apache so I've tried to change it with no avail (tried https://serverfault.com/a/612954). So instead I've added sleep and chmod the rights to 777.. and I have the same error.

Comment: I think single quotes are not needed in your path.

Comment: They're not there. The single quotes come from repr() indicating that variable is a string. The double quotes come from equal sign of format. A bit confusing, that's my bad. I just wanted to show that there are no wierd characters in those strings (like new lines and such).

Comment: As another attempt at figuring out what could possibly be wrong, can you try to create a file through the terminal and ensure the correct rights to the file and then place that file under the folder in question and try accessing it as web user.

Comment: I cannot think of any other reason that this would not work on windows docker but works on host machine.

Comment: Created a file with same rights (600 and web_portal:web_portal) as when it's uploaded and web_portal user can access it. I want to point out that web_portal user CAN access the file once the upload fails. When upload fails the file IS THERE, it's only during the execution of the whole code when web_portal can't access the file. It's like something locks that file after the os.rename is run, or during or idk. Thank you for your effort tho :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `MAX_UPLOADING_FILE_SIZE` in your `settings.py` file, this solution helps me im my projects:

```py
MAX_UPLOADING_FILE_SIZE = 31457280  # 30 MB
```

Comment: MAX_UPLOADING_FILE_SIZE setting is not a thing - doesn't exist. If you meant FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE and / or DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE I have them set, but they don't help in my situation - I can't fit uploaded files in memory. Some uploaded files exceed well beyond 1GB.